# List All Customers created in the last X minutes - Stripe REST API - How to pass created.gt?

Tags: api, rest, stripe-payments

I have a requirement to call Stripe List All Customers API. I want to find out customers who got created in the last X minutes. I was referring [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list?lang=curl#list_customers-created-lt). I am specifically interested to know the exact header value to use for created.gt.

it is working via curl if I pass the value like this below

```
-d limit=3 \
  -d created[gt]= 1599709192447\
  -G
```

But if i try passing it as created[gt] or created.gt in the rest header, it is simply ignoring that header name and returning the entire list.

I only see SDK examples. I don't see any REST API examples in the website. I have to do it the REST way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The format is correct - it is created[gt]. But it has to be passed as a URL Query String Parameter. I was passing it in the header.

It's a little confusing. The limit has to be passed in the header whereas this has to be passed as a URL parameter

Comment: It doesn't get passed in the header; it gets passed in the POST body.

Comment: it is a get method